# Convert dictionary to a string and separate by coma each key-value pair

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to write a simple function to update MySQL table from python dictionary:

```
data = {'foo':1, 'bar':2}
table = 'mytable'
pk = 'mypk'
pk_value = 1

sql = ''
sql += 'UPDATE ' + table
sql += 'SET ' + convert_dict_to_str(data)
sql += 'WHERE ' + pk
sql += ' = ' + pk_value
sql += ';'


def convert_dict_to_str(data):
    result = ''
    for key in data:
        result += "{key} = {value}".format(key=key, value=data[key])   
    return result

print convert_dict_to_str(data)
```

But I got stuck on how to convert dict into `"key = value, key = value"`?
In my example the desired output should be:

```
 'foo = 1, bar = 2'
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? My first quick glance looks okay.

Comment: You should be using parametrized statements instead of building your statements like this which is prone to SQL injections.

Comment: Hi @Pedro, can you please tell me little bit more about this?, I mean how to achieve what you saying.

Comment: Which MySQL DB API 2.0 driver are you using exactly so I can point you to the right place in its documentation? You can read more about SQL injections here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Comment: MySQLdb, I think I found the answer myself, but what can you recommend instead? I mean what's the other way to upload JSON into MySQL?

Comment: You can have a look at these examples which use parameters: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples. Especially interesting for your case is the last _multi-row insert_ example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> ", ".join(["=".join([key, str(val)]) for key, val in data.items()])
'foo=1, bar=2'
```

Comment: I want to exclude the key=val whose val is empty string, how can we consider it in this code?